# List all Top Level Folders in Google Drive api

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-realtime-api

IAM Working on app which use Google Drive API. Could I get top level folders in the Google drive using drive API?
What is the Scope For that?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had the same problem today. This is how i solved it:

```
function showTopLevel() { 
  var folders = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    Logger.log(folder.getName());
  }
}
```